# не обновляется npm

Tags: npm

делаю в терминале:

```
esin@lenovoVerm ~ $ sudo npm i -g npm@latest
 /home/esin/.npm-packages/bin/npx -> /home/esin/.npm-packages
 /lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
 /home/esin/.npm-packages/bin/npm -> /home/esin/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
 + npm@5.3.0
updated 1 package in 17.892s
esin@lenovoVerm ~ $ sudo npm -v -g
5.0.3
```

почему?

```
esin@lenovoVerm ~ $ which npm
/usr/bin/npm
```

и как это исправить все?

Comment: выполните в командной строке `which npm; where npm`, добавьте в вопрос ([edit]). Возможно, у вас он в двух местах установлен.

Comment: или попробуй выполнить `sudo npm -v -g`

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же проблема не нашел лучшего решения , чем установить nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
```

Через nvm npm установился с последней версией (5.3.0)